# Background color con 2 linear gradient

Tags: css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando maquetar este diseño, en donde la sección F tenga un background con un linear gradient

he intentado esto

```
#f{
    background-color: #113B67;
    color: #E7EBF0;

    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background:
    linear-gradient(45deg, #E7EBF0 32%, rgba(17,59,103,1) 32%, rgba(17,59,96,1) 64%,#E7EBF0 64%),
    linear-gradient(138deg, #E7EBF0 32%, rgba(17,59,103,1) 32%, rgba(17,59,96,1) 64%,#E7EBF0 64%);

    
  }
```

pero el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que el color azul quede como una flecha apuntando hacia arriba
Hay alguna forma de poder hacer esto con CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar algo como esto. Separando un div para crear el triángulo de la flecha y otro con el contenido.

```css
body {
  margin:0px;
}
.content {
  background:#40639B;
  width:60%;
  padding:7% 20% 10% 20%;
  color:#fff;
}

.arrow-up{
  height:100px;
}
.arrow-up:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #fff 49%, #40639B 50%);
}
.arrow-up:after {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #fff 49%, #40639B 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Contenido de la sección</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Pero el contendio de la sección quedaría en uno de los dos div, no?

Comment: Claro en el que he puesto el texto. Quedaría un div con el contenido y encima un div con forma de triángulo para hacer el efecto de flecha hacia arriba.

Comment: Eres un crack! gracias por la explicación, lo estoy aplicando